# Ajax username availability check in php oop structure

Tags: php, ajax, oop, validation

Understanding how ajax works has been really difficult for me. I think it's mainly because, somehow, I ended up writing php code in oop structure (I am a beginner, and it happened because of this php book about oop I read when I first started learning php), and I seem to have a problem connecting php class file (functions inside it) to ajax function.

I am trying to add a real-time username availability check feature to my web application (like the one you see in twitter's signup page).

I have two files, `register.php` and `class.register.php`

Inside `register.php` file, there are some php code that fires `class.register.php` file,
some html code, and some ajax code (haven't separated javascript file yet).

php part of `register.php` file looks like this,

```
<?php
require_once 'class/class.register.php';
$register = new Register();
if(isset($_POST['picked_username'])){
    $register->ajax_username();
}
?>
```

html part of `register.php` file looks like this,

```
<input type="text" name="username_input" id="username_input" value="" />
<span id="validate_username"></span>
```

ajax part of `register.php` file looks like this,

```
$("#username_input").keyup(function(){

    var picked_username = $("#username_input").val();
    $("#validate_username").text("loading…");

    $.ajax({
        type:"post",
        url:"register.php",
        data:{"picked_username":picked_username},
        success:function(result){
            if(result == "0"){
                $("#validate_username").text("available");
            }else if(result == "1"){
                $("#validate_username").text("not available");
            }
        },
        error:function(){
            $("#validate_username").text("something is wrong");
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

So basically, when you type something in the username_input area, it sends the data to the same page (`register.php`), and then triggers `isset($_POST['picked_username'])` php code on top of the page, which then calls `ajax_username();` function in the `class.register.php` file.

And this is the `ajax_username();` function in `class.register.php` file (used PDO).

```
public function ajax_username(){
    $picked_username = $_POST['picked_username'];

    $query = "SELECT username FROM mytable WHERE username = '$picked_username' LIMIT 1";
    $result = $this->db->query($query);
    $number = $result->rowCount();

    if($number == 0){
        echo '0';
    }elseif($number == 1){
        echo '1';
    }
}
```

And unfortunately, nothing happens. Can anyone please tell me what the problem is?

When I do UPDATE or INSERT query instead of SELECT, it actually works fine.
For instance, I used a very similar code to update checkbox value in the database with ajax.

```
public function update_checkbox(){
    $check_box = $_POST['check_box'];
    $query = "UPDATE mytable SET checkbox = '$check_box' WHERE id = $myid LIMIT 1";
    $result = $this->db->query($query);
}
```

I think this code works because it doesn't **echo** anything. And I don't think my ajax code is receiving any value from **echo**.

Please help me! I've been struggling with this problem for a while. Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Providing your SQL query is working as expected, try adding `console.log(result);` after `success:function(result){` add tell us what your function is returning (either in chrome developer console or firebug). I normally JSON encode my returned data. Also from a security perspective NEVER insert $_POST variables straight into your SQL code as you're inviting SQL Injection. Search for parametrised queries and/or mysql_real_escape_string()

Comment: @leejmurphy I've never used `console.log` before, and I am not sure if I used it correctly. On my `register.php` page, I did click "inspect element" using chrome, and typed `console.log(result);` in the console area, and it says "undefined." So instead, I put `alert(result);` right after `success:function(result){` and and ran the code, and the alert box is returning whole page starting from the doctype to all javascript (everything except php code). Something must be really wrong here right?

Comment: performing a query everytime the user presses a key doesn't look very friendly to the server. Might as well consider preloading your username list into a <datalist> or something then just check from that list whenever user press on a key. I'm not very sure about the security of that though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so thinking about what you said regarding the HTML being returned. Your code is this...

```
<?php
require_once 'class/class.register.php';
$register = new Register();
if(isset($_POST['picked_username'])){
    $register->ajax_username();
}
?>
```

The problem (or at least part) is after `$register->ajax_username();` is called I imagine the rest of your HTML page is being called after it. You will need to use `exit()` to prevent any additional code from being run. Try this

```
if($number == 0){
    exit('0');
}else{
    exit('1');
}
```

Also I can see rupesh-patel's point. The above is probably a more elegant solution. (we don't really need to check for any value other than 0).

Comment: You are the BEST. After replacing my code to the code you suggested, it works fine. Thank you so much!!

Comment: @Peter No problem, glad I could help. I do suggest you look into making your SQL query more secure though, have a search on here for SQL Injection.

Answer (score 1):

By looking your code I can point out one thing in ajax_username() function

```
if($number == 0){
        echo '0';
    }elseif($number == 1){
        echo '1';
    }
```

what will happen if your number is neither 0 nor 1, I think $number is NULL because `$result->rowCount()` returns NULL. You haven't included this case.
use this instead

```
if($number == 0){
        echo '0';
    }elseif($number == 1){
        echo '1';
    }
    else
    {
       echo '0'; //or any thing else
    }
```